# Do I need to set up NEO4J_IMPORT environment variable?

Tags: neo4j

```
cp -f data/*.csv ${NEO4J_IMPORT}/
cd "${NEO4J_HOME}"
time bin/cypher-shell < $tmp_dir/create_graph.cypher
```

I am seeing a script to create a neo4j database, but running into a problem:

```
cp: /person.csv: Read-only file system
Connection refused
```

I am on Mac and can echo the NEO4J_HOME variable, but no NEO4J_IMPORT. Should I set my own NEO4J_IMPORT environment variable when using cypher-shell to create a graph? Where to set the NEO4J_IMPORT environment variable, if it is a must?

Answer (score 0):

NEO4J_IMPORT need not be in env.

Probably neo4j instance is down or running or running on non standard port. Try this one.
In neo4j home path and make sure file has sufficient permission.

```
cat query.cypher | bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p neo4j -a localhost:7687 --format plain
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-syntax

Comment: I restarted the neo4j and uncomment this line: 'dbms.security.auth_enabled=true', but received this message when running the create graph script: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure. BTW, I installed the Neo4J Desktop with 3.5.12

Comment: Are you specifying the correct neo4j userid and password in your command line? The answer's command line is using "neo4j" for both.

Comment: Where to specify the username/pass? My command looks like: bin/cypher-shell < ~/data/create_graph.cypher. Where to get rid of the password and username settings? In the Desktop, I already uncommented "#dbms.security.auth_enabled=true"